# How do i find out the number of days in a previous month in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i find out the number of days in a previous month in Oracle

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first day of the *current* month with `trunc(sysdate, 'MM')`, then subtract a month to get the first day of the *previous* month; then use `last_day()` to get the last day of that month; then `extract()` the day number from that:

```
select extract(day from last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -1)))
from dual;

EXTRACT(DAYFROMLAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-1)))
------------------------------------------------------------
                                                          31
```

Mostly just for fun, you can see the numbers that gets for say the last six months with a hierarchical query:

```
select last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), - level)) as last_date,
  extract(day from last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), - level))) as last_day_number
from dual
connect by level <= 6;

LAST_DATE  LAST_DAY_NUMBER
---------- ---------------
2019-03-31              31
2019-02-28              28
2019-01-31              31
2018-12-31              31
2018-11-30              30
2018-10-31              31
```

---

As @GordonLinoff pointed out, the `trunc()` call is a bit redundant - because `add_months()` is quite forgiving - so you can simplify further to:

```
select extract(day from last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1)))
from dual;
```

You could also use subtract an interval instead, but then you do need to truncate the current date first, as that won't like dates at the end of the month if the preceding month has fewer days:

```
select extract(day from last_day(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') - interval '1' month))
from dual;
```

Comment: `trunc(sysdate)` is redundant, isn't it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - yes, I suppose so; up to the last_day part it keeps the time, but the extract ignores that anyway. (I as thinking it needed to trunc to month because of interval subtraction borking on some dates, forgetting `add_months()` is more forgiving...)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT 1 + LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE), -1)) - TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'MM')
from dual;

31
```